Order columns based of suffix condition in R
The name of my variables looks like this:
df <- data.frame(var_NA = 1:10, var = 11:20, var_Level = 21:30, var_Total = 31:40)

Except I have lots of variables. The key feature is that for every "mother" variable var, there are many "child" variables with different names (like var_NA and var_Level). Some "mothers" have more "children" than other. One thing is fixed though: there is always a child with suffix _NA.
What I want is to order columns like this:

mother variable
_NA child
the other children (if available)
mother variable
_NA child
the other children (if available)
.
.
.

In my example, outcome would be var,var_NA,var_Level,var_Total.
I've given up trying with select(ends_with()), relocate() and other comments. This is probably done best with regex, of which I am totally ignorant. Any ideas?

Have updated answer to correspond to the changes in the question.
Create nms to be the the names of df except that the name ending in _NA is replaced with the same name ending in just _ so that it sorts earlier.  Note that the $ in _NA$ means the end so that _NA$ only matches to a name ending in _NA .
Now the sorted order of nms applied to the columns of df sorts the columns of df as desired.
nms <- sub("_NA$", "_", names(df))
df[order(nms)]

giving (continued after output):
   var var_NA var_Level var_Total
1   11      1        21        31
2   12      2        22        32
3   13      3        23        33
4   14      4        24        34
5   15      5        25        35
6   16      6        26        36
7   17      7        27        37
8   18      8        28        38
9   19      9        29        39
10  20     10        30        40

Collating sequence
Note that the actual sort order will depend on the LC_COLLATE setting of the locale.  For example, note below that numbers sort before letters in both the English and C locale examples; however, in the C locale all upper case letters come before all lower case but not in the English locale.  In the above solution the var column will come first and the var_NA column will come second (as it corresponds to var_ in nms) in both locales but the actual order within the remaining names will be locale dependent.
Sys.getlocale() # shows locale being used including LC_COLLATE
## ..snip..

x <- c("0", "1", "2", "a", "b", "c", "A", "B", "C")

Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "en_US.utf8")
sort(x)
## [1] "0" "1" "2" "a" "A" "b" "B" "c" "C"

Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")
sort(x)
## [1] "0" "1" "2" "A" "B" "C" "a" "b" "c"

Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "") # set locale back to default

